thread function in Python
I write the code that the output is not expected.
2024-10-30 10:41:51,003 - INFO - Server listening on 127.0.0.1:65431
Received message: unencrypted from ('127.0.0.1', 62564)
Received message: unencrypted from ('127.0.0.1', 54766)
Message from 127.0.0.1:62564 - hi
**Message from 127.0.0.1:54766 - hello**

But the expected output should be
2024-10-30 10:41:51,003 - INFO - Server listening on 127.0.0.1:65431
Received message: unencrypted from ('127.0.0.1', 62564)
Received message: unencrypted from ('127.0.0.1', 54766)
Message from 127.0.0.1:62564 - hi
**Message from 127.0.0.1:62564- hello**

the server code
import socket
import threading
import logging

# Server settings
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 65431

# List to keep track of connected clients
clients = []
clients_lock = threading.Lock()

# Setting up logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# Setting up the server
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server.bind((HOST, PORT))
logging.info(f"Server listening on {HOST}:{PORT}")

def broadcast(message, sender_addr):
    with clients_lock:
        for client in clients:
            if client != sender_addr:
                try:
                    server.sendto(message, client)
                except Exception as e:
                    logging.error(f"Error sending message to {client}: {e}")
                    clients.remove(client)

def handle_client(addr):
    while True:
        if len(clients) == 2:
            try:
                message, _ = server.recvfrom(4096)
                if message:
                    decoded_message = message.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')
                    sender_info = f"{addr[0]}:{addr[1]}"
                    full_message = f"{sender_info}: {decoded_message}"
                    print(f"Message from {sender_info} - {decoded_message}")
                    #broadcast(full_message.encode('utf-8'), addr)
            except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
                logging.error(f"Unicode decode error: {e}")
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f"Error handling client message: {e}")
                with clients_lock:
                    if addr in clients:
                        clients.remove(addr)
                break

def main():
    while True:
        with clients_lock:
            if len(clients) < 2:
                # Receive message from client
                message, addr = server.recvfrom(4096)
                decoded_message = message.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')
                print(f"Received message: {decoded_message} from {addr}")
                
                if addr not in clients:
                    clients.append(addr)
                    threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(addr,)).start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

client code

import socket
import threading

# Server settings
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 65431

# Create a UDP socket
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Choose encryption method
encryption_method = input("Choose encryption method (unencrypted): ")

# Flag to stop the receiving thread
stop_thread = threading.Event()

def receive_messages(client_socket):
    while not stop_thread.is_set():
        try:
            message, _ = client_socket.recvfrom(4096)
            if encryption_method == 'unencrypted':
                print(f"Server: {message.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')}")
        except Exception as e:
            if not stop_thread.is_set():
                print(f"Error receiving message: {e}")
            break

# Start a thread to receive messages
thread = threading.Thread(target=receive_messages, args=(client,))
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()

# Send the encryption method choice once
choice_method = encryption_method.encode('utf-8')
client.sendto(choice_method, (HOST, PORT))

try:
    while True:
        sentence = input("")
        if sentence:
            if encryption_method == 'unencrypted':
                message = sentence.encode('utf-8')
                client.sendto(message, (HOST, PORT))
            print(f"You: {sentence}")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\nConnection closed.")
finally:
    stop_thread.set()
    client.close()

Thank you

datagrams are connectionless, so keeping track of "connected" clients doesn't make sense.  message, _ = server.recvfrom(4096) is throwing away the sender's address, which could be from either client.

It's not obvious at a glance what's different between your actual and expected output. Spell that out explicitly in English, don't expect readers to parse the results against each other and infer; similarly, describe in English why you think something specific to threading caused that problem.

Thank you everyone especially @MarkTolonen. The problem is solved.
